# How to delete rows that have the same value in 1 column and same corresponding value in the other? (Values are text)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

If multiple values in column B are same, and corresponding values in column C are also same, then delete the rows containing those values otherwise, nothing. How do I do this in Excel (VBA)?

```
 B     C
XYZ    Y
XYZ    Y
ABC    Y
XYZ    N
```

So the result should be something like :

```
 B     C
XYZ    Y
ABC    Y
XYZ    N
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if text@B2 == text@B3 && text@C2 == text@C3, then delete row 3`
Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA.
Just mark your data and go to the "Data" tab. Press "Remove duplicates" and make sure that both of the checkboxes called "Column B" and "Column C" are checked.

This removes rows if and only if the values in column B and C correspond to a duplicate row somewhere else in the marked data.

Comment: Actually, I posted this question cause that did not work.
Like, there was literally 2 names which were same, no trailing spaces, nothing, and 2 adjacent values, again the same, but it wouldn't remove it.

Comment: I have tried your sample data and it works fine; removed the 2nd row with no problem. Could you re-check your data?